# Error linking MS Access to SAP Hana database

Tags: hana

I am trying to link an Access 2016 DB to tables in a SAP Hana database using ODBC. When I try to link to tables

" '_SYS_BIC_XYZ_PUBLISHED_Customer_Service_Tran/CVC_SERVICE_ORDER_ACTUAL_COST_REV' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not to long. "

I'm able to connect to all other tables, but this one is giving me a grief. I suspect it's because of long name. But I cannot change the table name in SAP Hana source.
I found this article:
http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/linking-microsoft-access-2010-tables-to.html
but still cannot change the table in SAP Hana itself. Is there any other way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

1. create a **synonym** for the view and give the synonym a shorter name.
2. create a **view** with a shorter name that projects the calculation view with the long name.

In your question, you refer to the DB object `_SYS_BIC_XYZ_PUBLISHED_Customer_Service_Tran/CVC_SERVICE_ORDER_ACTUAL_COST_REV` as a table. That's likely incorrect, as the naming (`_SYS_BIC`-schema and `CVC_` prefix) indicates that this is in fact a calculation view.
This also means you will only be able to *read* from this view, but not able to change data in it.